# How do I fetch users from IdP-ADFS in Java program?

Tags: java, saml, saml-2.0, spring-saml, adfs3.0

We have a Web-based application which talks with IdP and IdP uses ADFS with SAML.
We are using Spring Security framework in between IdP and our Server, now, we are able to authenticate user at IdP and sending user name into our Application server(without re-authenticating).

To assign different roles, we need all users at our Application server(we assign privileges at application level).

So my question is how do I fetch all users from ADFS into my application server?

Answer (score 1):

ADFS sits on top of AD.

ADFS has nothing whatsoever to do with user management.

So you need to migrate users out of AD.

You can do this with LDAP commands e.g. [Howto: (Almost) Everything In Active Directory via C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C) and [Everything in Active Directory via C#.NET 3.5 (Using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90142/Everything-in-Active-Directory-via-C-NET-Using).

Answer (score 0):

ADFS is a SAML Identity Provider and is not a queryable source, like LDAP or a relational database is. To query a complete list of users, the party providing the ADFS service will need to provide an alternative solution to "get all users".

Products like SharePoint need a custom people picker when integrating with SAML IdPs. This is not directly applicable to you, but is generally related.  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaevans/2013/05/26/fixing-people-picker-for-saml-claims-users-using-ldap/, will give you some ideas